# Any setting to avoid using all memory in apache drill when reading lots of json files and output to a single file?

Tags: apache-drill

May I know if there is any setting to avoid drill using all direct memory, when reading many big json files (20kb per file, with 100k+) and output to a file?

E.g., by running query like below, say there are 2k json files at stroageplugin.root.`/inputpath/`, each file has about 40k bytes strings in the "Content" attribute. The query will consume about 80MB direct memory to complete this. If there are 100k json files, the query will consume 4GB direct memory to complete.

Do we have a way to reduce the direct memory consumption here when merging lots of files into a single file?

CREATE TABLE stroageplugin.output.`/outputpath/` AS
SELECT Id, CreatedTime, Content
FROM stroageplugin.root.`/inputpath/`;

Answer (score 0):

You can configure memory settings using environment variables (or configuring `<drill_installation_directory>/conf/drill-env.sh` directly):

```
DRILL_HEAP=8G
DRILL_MAX_DIRECT_MEMORY=10G
DRILLBIT_CODE_CACHE_SIZE=1024M
```

See https://drill.apache.org/docs/configuring-drill-memory/